# JavaFX and CSS Basic ?'s (regarding Checkboxes)

Tags: css, checkbox, javafx

I have a couple questions regarding JavaFX (1.3) and CSS. First of all, when I create a CheckBox node and set its styleclass, I can't actually get the checkbox to show up. It just looks like a text-label. Do I have to specify something specific to actually get the checkbox to appear?

Also, what is the CSS class/id I would use to modify all checkboxes in a program?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the JavaFX CSS Reference Guide?

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: That was my starting point... perhaps somebody else can make more sense of the CheckBox than I did. Thanks, JimClarke.

Comment: Checkbox has a styleClass of "check-box" that includes the button and labeled CSS keys. The actual checkbox contains a Label (styleclass is supposed to be "label" not sure it is though) and a Region (box that holds check mark), the styleClass of the Region is "box". The mark is "mark". You can look at com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css within <JAVAFX_HOME>/lib/desktop/javafx-ui-controls.jar for all the CSS definitions.

Comment: If you change the styleClass for the checkbox you would need to add a rule for the "box" and the "mark". Something like: .my-check-box *.box { -fx-padding: 3 3 3 3; .... }

Answer (score 0):

I think the place you need to look at is this forum post:

- [Styling a checkbox](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2350619) and also:
- [Checkbox](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/checkbox.htm) in the UI controls

I had similar issues with ListBox where the control is constructed from a number of components and has a bunch of different pseudo classes to be 'configured' depending on what you need it do look-like.

The [Styling a checkbox](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2350619) thread points you to the javaFX runtime:  $lib\ext\jfxrt.jar.

If you look in: com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/

- caspian/caspian.css
- moderna/moderna.css

You get the full naked 'defaults' CSS for the your controls.  That said I am on here today to find out

- [A method to algn JavaFX checkbox label text with the text on a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435805/a-method-to-algn-javafx-checkbox-label-text-with-the-text-on-a-line)

... how to align the text base-line, so there's still work to do before it just magically looks right *lol*