# A method to algn JavaFX checkbox label text with the text on a line

Tags: java, css, checkbox, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I have a plain CheckBox in an FXML file on the same line as some other controls and labels in a HBox.

The checkBox label text-base is about 6px units lower than ALL the other text and labels on the same line (HBox).

I can manually line things up in SceneBuilder by specifying a **padding-bottom** value of: **6**.  I wanted to put that into the CSS so all checkbox labels would be "lined-up", but everthing I've tried is ignored and doesn't show in the CSS Analyzer (too).

I looked through the Checbox default styling as pointed out here:

- [Styling a checkbox](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2350619) and also:
- [Checkbox](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/checkbox.htm) in the UI controls

I had similar issues with ListBox where the control is constructed from a number of components. You have to know which '*thing*' is relevant.  However, looking through: com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/

- caspian/caspian.css

I can't pick the component that makes the text label lower than other text on the same line/row.  Add to that, the fact that specifying the padding in the SceneBuilder designer layout, will fix the issue on a one-by-one (manual) basis, it just seems strange that it won't work for:

```
.check-box {
    padding-bottom: 6px;  /* or just 6  */
}
```

Does not work on the following FXML mark-up.

```
  <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" >
     <children>
        <CheckBox fx:id="acknowledged" alignment="TOP_LEFT" styleClass="normal" text="00">
           <padding>
              <Insets bottom="6.0" left="4.0" right="8.0" />
           </padding>
        </CheckBox>
        <Button fx:id="detailButton" text="%alarm.detail.label" />
        <Label fx:id="alarmType" styleClass="normal" text="%alarm.type.value">
           <padding>
              <Insets left="8.0" right="8.0" />
           </padding>
        </Label>
     </children>
  </HBox>
```

The objective is to define the padding-bottom via CSS rather than have to do it manually in the FXML:

```
    <padding>
         <Insets bottom="6.0" left="4.0" right="8.0" />
   </padding>
```

Any ideas?

To be clear, the visual result for this row is that the checkbox itself has a base-line smaller/lower than the other elements (button, label).  The CheckBox label is also subsequently "below" the other elements.  If we can pad using CSS, then we don't need to manually maintain the layouts.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, alignment problems should be solved by the layout (vs. tweaking paddings or such). So first stop to a solution could be the doc of the parent pane, here HBox:

> The alignment of the content is controlled by the alignment property,
>   which defaults to Pos.TOP_LEFT.

That might be consistent with what you are be seeing (can't be 100% certain, though, as you forgot to include a runnable example ;-) If all other components on the line are accidentally being same height or filling the box with the checkbox smaller, it will positioned at the top of the pane.

Assumed solution is to change the pane's alignment to BASELINE_XX, quick check in code works fine for me:

```
private Parent getContent() {
    HBox box = new HBox(new TextField("something"), 
            new CheckBox("soso"), new Button("hello"));
    box.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
    return box;
}
```

Comment: Yes -- That's correct, "alignment of the content is controlled by the alignment property" and all the elements are aligned Bottom-Left.  However the CheckBox element and label text are about 6px _LOWER_ than the other text item in this HBox -- Hence the need for the question.  Also with Center-Left, every element is aligned on the same base-line and the CheckBox is still about 6 px too low.

Comment: If asked, it seems that the sub-components of the checkbox 'eat' some pixels.  In the example "soso" will be about 6px lower than "something" and the "hello" button.  I would prefer a layout solution.  So far setting the in-line padding is the only adequate method so far.

Comment: @will sounds like you forgot to include all relevant details in your question ;-) As far as I know, you can't get the text aligned for any other alignment than baseline: if they do for bottom/top, that's pure coincidence. Anyway, same procedure as always: for best help, please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: In the question: "_The checkBox label text-base is about 6px units lower than ALL the other text and labels on the same line (HBox)_."  The CSS shown in the question does NOT add padding-bottom to CheckBoxes.  The aim was to correct the problem for all CheckBox-es via a style sheet.  Since it _is-what-it-is_ the question is really, "What's the correct styling for the *.check-box* class or sub-class for this?"

Comment: @will only with an alignment of bottom ... baseline is just fine. Again: you can't _expect_ text to be aligned except in baseline, if it is for others, you are just lucky. So: good luck :-)